# Search text/character in a column that contain string of characters and return info on adjacent column

Tags: excel

I would like to search if a text/value (Column A) contained in column B where there are string of characters, then print out the info on adjacent column C.

E.g.:

```
A     B                   C   D 
C136  C125,C136,C138,C150 USA USA 
C150  C138, C145,C150     CAN CAN 
X5    C138, C145,C150     XYZ False
```

Comment: So D should line up with B or A?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in your output column (Column D):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B2)),C2)
```

Comment: Note: I would like to print out info from another column if match found. The content in search columns has a string of characters that separate by comma. Eg: C1, C2, C3, C4, C55, C60. Say my search string is C3. Then it matched that column. Then print out the info from the ad junction column.

Comment: @randy Could you please edit your question to include the input you have and your desired output?

Comment: With the table above, Input is in cell A1. Search character is"C136"; Search table is from B1:B3; if matched print out corresponding content in C on Column D. See C136  matched C136 in B. Then print out USA in column D.

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B2)),C2) only work when search cell has only value. In my case, the search content is bunch of string with comma separate them. Plus the search content will be whole column instead of a cell.